# setup.py, separate source folders and unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, distutils

Here's my directory structure:

```
myproject/
  src/
    some_package/
  test/
    test_some_package/
      test_something.py
      utilities.py
setup.py
```

I'd like to configure setup.py such that

- `setup.py install` Installs packages under `src/` but nothing from `test/`.
- `setup.py test` Runs all unit-tests found under `test/`.

All tests use `unittest`. There is some helper modules under `test/` that don't contain tests but are used by tests, therefore they need to be in `sys.path` during testing.

Right now my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
 from setuptools import setup, find_packages
 setup(
     name = "myproject",
     version = "0.1",
     packages = find_packages("src"),
     package_dir = {'':'src'},
     test_suite="???"
 )
```